# c# FTP to FileZilla Server file name save issue

Tags: c#, filezilla

Whenever I use this code it uploads the jpeg, but the jpegs name is `STOR` with no extension on the server.

Any idea as to why this happens or how I change the file name when saving from my C# desktop application to my FileZilla FTP Server??

Here is the basic code, the names have been changes to protect the innocent ;)

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.BaseAddress = "ftp://mysite.com";
client.UploadFile(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, "C:\mypics\pic1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
client.UploadFile(remoteName, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile , @"C:\mypics\pic1.jpg");
```

WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile is a string whose value happens to be STOR so the compiler is assuming your are using the client.UploadFile(remoteName, localName) overload which is why your file is named STOR

Comment: I was torn as to which answer was the best. Your answer was correct, explained why it was happening, and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

@sgmoore answered the question. You need just use method correctly:

```
client.UploadFile("pic1.jpg", "C:\mypics\pic1.jpg");
```

first argument is remote file name, second is path to local file.

You can also try some other ftp client implementations in .net (anyway FTP is implemented badly in .NET standard library), I've used [ftplib](http://ftplib.codeplex.com/) and it's working good.

Comment: Great answer! I had to check who answered first to be fair.
I would give you the check tooo if I could!

Comment: @GregH that's ok, I totally agree that sgmoore was the first who gave correct answer, and anyway it's just some virtual score after all, I didn't take it that seriously :)